# How to give space between each tab in the navigation using Jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-tabs

This is what I have  http://jsbin.com/ipipu3/86/edit

I would like to have a space between each tab.

When I am trying to add Icons before the tab texts it works fine but when I give some padding it looks ugly.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please be more elaborate, where do you want the space? Show us an example of the ugly version with icons and then tell us how you want it to be.

Comment: Leave without the icons can you say me how to give space in the navigation as I have already mentioned.

Comment: using CSS, add left margin for '.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the answer was provided above in a comment, but I don't think any "Answer" was provided with actual code demonstrating the concept. I'm using `15px` as an exaggerated example.

```
$( "#tabs ul li").css({'margin-right':'15px'});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ipipu3/89/edit